# How to convert list to integer

Tags: python

When I run

```
print(c)
```

I get the output

```
[45]
```

How do I remove the `[ ]` and get output like this as an integer?

```
45
```

Because I want to print this but It won't run.

```
print(b[c:c+50])
```

Comment: look up list indexing

Comment: Can you share more code such that one can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first element of that array.

```
print(c[0])
```